# Using Parameters to generate date range

Tags: sql-server

So I have multiple reports I am trying to merge into one report. The big issue is that one report is run every two weeks and the other is run once a month.

The date range for the report was created using this sql

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) <= 15 THEN
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) + 15
        ELSE
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) , 0)
    END AS LO_DATE
```

So I tried adding a parameter that I could use that would basically say, hey if this is checked, then always run it for the whole month not the last two weeks. That sql looks like this.

```
IF (@RUN_FOR_MONTH = 'true')
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) <= 15 THEN
                DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) + 15
            ELSE
                DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) , 0)
        END AS LO_DATE
ELSE
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) , 0) AS LO_DATE
```

However I keep getting this error:

**The report parameter ‘LO_DATE’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter “RUN_FOR_MONTH”. Forward dependencies are not valid.**

I am new to using SQL Server Report Builder, so if you need more information, please ask and I'll provide it.

REQUESTED CHANGE - I still get the same error

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @RUN_FOR_MONTH = 'true' THEN
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) , 0)
        WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) <= 15 THEN
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) + 15
        ELSE
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) , 0)
    END AS LO_DATE
```

Comment: make it so there is one SELECT, then a CASE within a CASE perhaps - so put your @RUN_FOR_MONTH logic into the CASE

Comment: Sounds like you have the parameter `LO_DATE` higher in your parameter list than `RUN_FOR_MONTH`. Move the `RUN_FOR_MONTH` up in the parameter list. so that it is above `LO_DATE`. Parameters in SSRS are derived sequentially. If you base parameter's value off another then that parameter must be lower in the list, so that the one it is dependant on can be derived first.

Comment: @Cato do you mean like that? If so, I still get the same error.

Comment: @Larnu I just saw the little arrows in the report builder for moving parameters!!! Thank you so much!!!!!! They should make those arrows stand out more.

Comment: @Larnu Can you put your comment as an answer so I can mark it, for future people.

Comment: I try these sentences and I don't get any error (SQL 2014). How have you declared LO_DATE ?

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh was just waiting for VS to boot up so i could provide an image to assist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in SSRS are derived sequentially. If you have a parameter that is based off another's value, you must list those parameters in in the correct sequential order. Take the below

[image]

In this example, `@DateFrom` would be evaluated first, and then `@DateTo`; thus `@DateFrom` cannot depend on `@DateTo` (however the reverse is fine).

If, for example, the value of `@DateFrom` was `DateAdd("d", -2, @DateTo)` you would receive the error you have above. You would need to select `@DateTo` and click the Up Arrow icon (Or select `@DateFrom` and the down arrow)

Comment: your version of report builder is much nicer, mine is older and I have much smaller arrows that are blue on top of a blue bar. lol

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh VS2017. SSDT 2017 supports SSRS 2012+ (Not 2008, which requires BIDS). I'm actually still using SQL Server 2012 at the moment, but SSMS 2017 and VS 2017 work great with it (you just can't make use of all the features).